# react rendering heap memory issue?

Tags: reactjs, redux, render

Hi I am planner of one company who work for company providing mobile service for Korean physician.

And we are preparing for renovation of our mobile web service with React-redux
Like facebook and linkedin, new UI of our service is ‘Timeline’-style, so performance of infinite scroll including rendering and loading time is very critical.

And we have difficulty in tuning of it. 
As the number of scrolling increases, some components of contents are delayed to render(android browser), or have to wait for a while, partially rendered(IOS BROWSER).

http://image.medigate.net/new/capture.gif

We checked performance of it with chrome browser (desktop)

http://image.medigate.net/new/graph.png

I would appreciate your help in advance.

(react 16.3.2 / we use react-waypoint)

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest looking into optimisations to avoid unnecessary re-rendering:
https://marmelab.com/blog/2017/02/06/react-is-slow-react-is-fast.html

As much as react is fast for rendering it also has the weakness of triggering unnecessary re-renders, which you can avoid by following some of the advice in the linked article.